# Related information from two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP and MySQL.  I'm not sure I know enough to even phrase my question right.  Bear with me...  I want to relate information in two tables together.  And I'm not exactly sure how to do that.  Here's a related example.

Say I have 1 table called users that has the following user information:

id

username

password

favorite_movies

In table 2, I have details about movies

id

title

year

Say I want to create a web application where a user can add/remove movies to their "favorites".  The user should be able to any number of favorite movies associated with their account.

Questions...

How should I store the information in the "favorite_movies" field?

I have considered storing information in favorite_movies by json_encode($array) and json_decode($array) to story an array of movie ids in the profile.  Is there a better way to store a reference to the movie that exists in the movie database?

What mysql query do I run on the database to get a list of all users that like a movie of a given title?

What mysql query do I run on the database to get a list of all movies that a user likes?

Given my json_encode/decode solution this seems like the tricky one to me.  I have an array of values...how do I apply that array to the query?

I suspect there's a database-esque name for what I'm describing here.  What is it so I can research it further??

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to store "favorite movies" in a field.  You want a separate table, `user_movies` with fields like:

- user_movie_id
- user_id
- movie_id

This is an association table.

If you want the list of movies as ids, then you do something like:

```
select um.user_id, group_concat(um.movie_id)
from user_movies um 
group by um.user_id;
```

Comment: +1, if you store data like Gordon suggested, you can do cool queries to show things like 59 out of 61 who have favorited a certain movie also favorited some other certain movie as a suggestion to users kind'a thing.